# BadPaddingException while performing symmetric encryption decryption

Tags: java, exception, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Am getting exception while doing decryption as per the below logic. Please suggest me any issue in the below code snippet. Encryption is fine and able to encrypt.

```
public String encryptDataSymmetric(String dataTobeEncrypted) {
    String encryptedData = null;
    try {
        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        SecureRandom securerandom = new SecureRandom();
        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keygenerator.init(192, securerandom);
        SecretKey key = keygenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        // cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        encryptedData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cipher.doFinal(dataTobeEncrypted.getBytes(CHARSET)))
                .trim();
        System.out.println("---encryptedData-----" + encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encryptedData;
}

public String decryptDataSymmetric(String dataTobeDecrypted) {
    String decryptedData = null;
    try {
        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        SecureRandom securerandom = new SecureRandom();
        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keygenerator.init(192, securerandom);
        SecretKey key = keygenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        decryptedData = new String(
                DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(cipher.doFinal(dataTobeDecrypted.getBytes()))));
        System.out.println("---decryptedData----" + decryptedData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
```

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted     at
> org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown
> Source)

Comment: Don't generate a new key on decryption again, you need to use the one used in encryption function.

Answer (score 3):

Not a Java guy, but you need to decode from Base64 to byte array, before passing it to the cipher when you are decrypting it, not after you attempt to decrypt it.

Base64 encoding is to encode byte stream into ascii characters, for transmission purposes. On the receiving end of the transmissiong you need to first convert from base64 encoding to byte stream again.

And after decrypt, you will have to convert the decrypted byte array into string.

In summary, decryption has to undo the steps of your encryption method.

Encryption Method:

- From string to plain byte array via UTf8
- Plain byte array to encrypted byte array via cipher
- Encrypted byte array to printable/serializable string via base64 encode

Decryption method:

- Printable/serialized string to encrypted byte array via base64 decode
- Encrypted byte array to plain byte array via cipher
- Plain byte array to string via UTF from bytes to string call.

Those being said, there are some problems with your code.
I was able to put together this Java sample code to demonstrate only the points I will make here.

- **First DO NOT USE AES with CBC alone!!! It is vulnerable to Padding Oracle attack.** Without going into details, that means someone **can decrypt your** encrypted values **very efficiently** if your system **gives even the slightest** hint (even time difference) that an encrypted messsage is correctly padded or not. DO NOT use the code I wrote below for the same reason.
- Use an Authenticated Encryption scheme or algorith.
- It is better to find a reputable library that does this and use that instead of writing your own.
- You need to create an IV for each encrypted message.IV's have to generated from cryptographically strong random generators. Below code tries to do that.
- You send (or store) the IV with the encrypted message (cipher text). IV is not a secret.
- In the below code the key is generated once as random. And then passed to encryption and decryption methods. You need to do same, create the key you will use once. And then find a secure way (a vault type structure/service) to store the key you use.
- You need to consider and makes plans on what you are going to do if key somehow got compromised? Look into key expiration schemes, sliding keys etc...
- In the below code, not being a Java developer I tried to do as simplest and as standard methods I could find to demonstrate. Your mileage may vary.

```
/*
DO NOT USE THIS CODE! It is vulnerable to Padding Oracle Attack!
Instead use an Authenticated Encryption scheme or algorithm.
This code is written for demonstration purpose only!! Not secure!!
*/
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.Console;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {


public static String encryptDataSymmetric(String dataTobeEncrypted, SecretKey key) {
    String encryptedData = null;
    try {
        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        
        SecureRandom securerandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        securerandom.nextBytes(ivBytes);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(dataTobeEncrypted.getBytes(CHARSET));

        System.out.println("---IV----" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ivBytes));
        
        byte[] ivAndCipherText = new byte[ivBytes.length + cipherText.length];
        
        System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, ivAndCipherText, 0, ivBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, ivAndCipherText, ivBytes.length, cipherText.length);
        encryptedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ivAndCipherText);
        System.out.println("---encryptedData-----" + encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encryptedData;
}

public static String decryptDataSymmetric(String cipherBase64Encoded, SecretKey key) {
    String encryptedData = null;
    try {
        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        
        byte[] ivAndCipherText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherBase64Encoded);
        
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        System.arraycopy(ivAndCipherText, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[ivAndCipherText.length - iv.length];
        System.arraycopy(ivAndCipherText, iv.length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.length);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),CHARSET);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encryptedData;
}


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SecureRandom securerandom = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keygenerator.init(192, securerandom);
            SecretKey key = keygenerator.generateKey();
            System.out.println("---key---" + key.getEncoded());
        
        
            String str = "Hello bye";
            //Console.Write(decryptDataSymmetric(encryptDataSymmetric(str)));
            System.out.println(str);
            String encrypted = encryptDataSymmetric(str, key);
            String plainText = decryptDataSymmetric(encrypted, key);
            System.out.println("plaintext: " + plainText);
            System.out.println("The end!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got to agree with PhazorP's comments above.

- DO NOT USE AES with CBC alone
- Use an Authenticated Encryption scheme or algorith.

I encourage you to use an authenticated encryption algorithm. Here is a short blog [article](https://www.ubiqsecurity.com/blog/understanding-authenticated-encryption-an-explainer) I wrote a while ago that may help.

Here is some [java](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-java) code as well for AES-GCM if you want to take a look.